# Find which node is printing a /rosout message

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to find out which node a message in /rosout is coming from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341403/find-which-node-is-printing-a-/rosout-message/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-10**:
Are you asking in the context of the log lines printed on your console, or are you subscribing to the messages on the `/rosout` topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried [rqt_console](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_console)? It displays and filters ROS messages.
You can see the messages and which node is publishing them.

---

Originally posted by [EFernandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/13791/efernandes/) with karma: 51 on 2020-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0